# 'Vector' operating on many vectors to minimize scalar function. How do I minimize it with respect to this 'vector'?

Tags: calculus, optimization, vector-spaces, nonlinear-optimization

I've done optimization before, but today I'm trying to do some exact nonlinear optimization in a problem with 2 vector spaces. I do not yet see a parallel for this in matrix operations if there is one. I've really tried looking for this online and here, but I don't know what to call the construction I've made.

Here is a minimal example. Say you have just N=4 vectors that are all in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$A = \langle 1, 2, 3\rangle$

$B = \langle 4, 5, 6\rangle$

$C = \langle 7, 8, 9\rangle$

$D = \langle 10,11,12\rangle$

I am finding a M-dimensional 'vector' $X$ (an array of scaling parameters) that minimizes another scalar function, by solving a system of nonlinear equations that each involve a few elements in $X$, and each element in this 'vector' operates on the above vectors.

$X = [x_0, x_1, x_2]$

Example scalar, polynomial objective function to get the idea, not my real function which is 2000+ characters when written concisely with sigma notation:

$f(X, A, B, C, D) = (x_0 A) \cdot (x_1 B) + (x_1 B) \cdot (x_2 C) + (x_2 C) \cdot (x_0 D)$

I also have vectors in the function I need to do dot products with, of a form like $(x_0 A) + (x_1 B)$, which are functions of $X$, $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$.

Now I'm having to solve the gradient of, say, $(x_0 A) + (x_1 B)$ with respect to the M dimensions of X, and I don't know if I'm breaking any rules. So in this example I would like to know... is $\nabla ((x_0 (A \cdot B)) + (x_1 (C \cdot D)))$ equal to $[(A \cdot B), (C \cdot D), 0]$ or no? And is it still even true that $\nabla (V \cdot V) = 2 V \cdot \nabla V$ in this use-case?

---

EDIT: It looks like the gradient with respect to $X$works out. Not a proof of course, but this example seems to work...

Assume $\nabla (V \cdot V) = 2 V \cdot \nabla V$

$\nabla ( (x_0 A + x_1 B) \cdot (x_0 A + x_1 B) ) = 2 (x_0 A + x_1 B) \cdot \nabla (x_0 A + x_1 B)$

$ \nabla ( x_0^2 A \cdot A + 2 x_0 x_1 A \cdot B + x_1^2 B \cdot B) = 2 (x_0 A + x_1 B) \cdot \langle A, B, 0 \rangle)$

$\langle 2 x_0 A \cdot A + 2 x_1 A \cdot B, 2 x_0 A \cdot B + 2 x_1 B \cdot B, 0 \rangle = 2 \langle x_0 A \cdot A + x_1 B \cdot A, x_0 A \cdot B + x_1 B \cdot B, 0 \rangle$

$2 \langle x_0 A \cdot A + x_1 A \cdot B, x_0 A \cdot B + x_1 B \cdot B, 0 \rangle = 2 \langle x_0 A \cdot A + x_1 A \cdot B, x_0 A \cdot B + x_1 B \cdot B, 0 \rangle$

---

But my main question here is, can someone tell me what branch of mathematics this $X$ 'vector' is in?

UPDATE: Using the gradient is working, but I'd still like to know what branch of mathematics this is because $(x_0 A + x_1 B) \cdot \langle A, B, 0 \rangle$ looks unlike anything I've seen before. I have not yet thought of a better way to rewrite these expressions either.

Comment: Hello Larry. I am not sure what are you looking for? Problem statement does not sound clear.

Comment: Hi I can tell I need to read more about geometric algebra and/or algebraic geometry, but, as I have not taken a course in it and I don't have time to right now, I just would like someone to point me in the right direction to be able to do dot products and gradients with respect to this 'meta-dimension.' See...I don't know what to call it, so I can't google it, and I can't solve it. That's the problem.

Comment: Is your function $f$, quadratic in the elements of the vector $X$ ? or does it involve more complicated expressions such as $x_0 x_1 x_2$ or $\sin(x_0) cos(x_1) $ ?

Comment: Hi @GeometryLover, it gets as complicated as $x_0 + x_0 x_1 + x_2^4$ No special functions and no trigonometry. Just lots of ugly multiplication and division.

Comment: Can you give an example of how a term like $x_2^4$ would arise ? The only way I can envision would be something like $((x_2 A)\cdot (x_2 B))((x_2 C)\cdot (x_2 D))=x_2^4 (A\cdot B)(C\cdot B)$.

Comment: @Semiclassical exactly. That is how it arises.

Comment: Alright. In that case it seems like you can simplify the description as follows: You have some polynomial function of the variables $x_0,x_1,x_2$ where the coefficients are themselves polynomial functions of the inner products. What I would stress here is that if you're optimizing over $X$, then the origin of the coefficients is irrelevant: they're fixed the moment you specify the vectors $A,B,C,$ etc. So in that respect you're just optimizing a generic polynomial function---no need to consider dot products.

Comment: That sounds to me like a better description than I gave, thanks. Not sure I understand the relevance of the origins being fixed. I can't tell a dot product from an inner product. But like you said the coefficients $x_0, x_1, x_2$ are themselves polynomial functions of the inner products, so I do need to consider those inner products. So I should just stop calling them dot products? Where can I read about this and/or do you know how to do the gradient?

Comment: As I understand it, $A, B, C, D$ are fixed/bound while $x_0, x_1, x_2$ are free variables.

Comment: I meant origin as "source", i.e., the optimization process doesn't care about where the constant coefficients come from. As such, you'd just differentiate in the usual way: $cx^2$ gives $2cx$ just like it usually would, regardless of whether $c$ also happens to be a dot product. (To make an analogy: If I'm deciding between two objects of equal utility but different market price, it hardly matters _why_ one is cheaper when it comes to my decision.)

Comment: I find that quite cool about math. I finally realized I could test out my simplified problem to see if the gradient methods I know still work here, and indeed they did. I still don't have much of a grasp on how these two vector spaces are interacting though. I think it's fair to say they're independent vector spaces, and maybe that's the only statement that really matters with regard to the math one can do with respect to either vector space.